# Create objects with unique generated ID (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

This might be a stupid question but I need a system that takes user input for a name, student ID# and grade level and stores them in objects, each with unique userIDs that are auto generated. It would work like this:

```
What is your name? >> Josh
What is your ID#? >> 12345
What grade are you in? >> 11
```

And it creates an object like so:

```
student000001 = {
name = "Josh",
id = 12345,
grade = 11
}
```

so that I can reference data using `student000001.grade` to get `11` for example.

the 000001 would increment by 1 for each object, so the next would be 000002 and so on.

Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way? Is this not the standard or secure/safe way to write code like this? I'm looked this up before but haven't found any solid answers. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[KISS Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is not as simple as one might think. On software development it basically means **to do the most basic think that could possible work** (phrase taken from TDD by Example by Kent Beck).

Is there any chance for two students to have the same id? If the answer is no, then I would use the student Id as unique id.

Edit: another link on the KISS rule: [https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/kiss.html](https://people.apache.org/%7Efhanik/kiss.html)

> A common problem among software engineers and developers today is that they tend to over complicate problems.